# How do I call a function to run in a graph window in a specific pattern?

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns

I have a function with objects that has to run at specific points in the graph window.

Each line represents the function (100x100) in what it is supposed to be a 500x500 window.

```
-----
 ---
  -
 ---
-----
```

I know how to make it run like this:

```
-----
-----
-----
-----
-----
```

by using nested loops.

```
def AssortmentOfObjects(size):
    win =GraphWin("Object assortment", size,size)
    ypoint = 0
    for y in range(5):
        xpoint = 0
        for x in range(5):
            Objects(win, xpoint, ypoint)
            xpoint = xpoint + 100
        ypoint = ypoint + 100
```

Apparently you can use if statements to make them run in a tessellation.
I just have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Objects you need to know the indentation, and the number (range of `x`). You can get both with the following:

```
n = 5
half = n // 2
for y in range(n):
    indent = (half - abs(half-y))
    x_count = n - (2 * indent)
    print(indent, x_count)
```

this will print:

```
0 5
1 3
2 1
1 3
0 5
```

(i.e. zero indentation on the first line, with 5 elements, one indent on the second with 3 elements, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine which points to draw; something like:

```
if shoulddraw(x,y):
    Objects(win,xpoint,ypoint)
```

Assuming that x gets bigger as you go to the right and y gets bigger as you go down, it looks like you want to draw when y<=x<=4-y (the top half) or 4-y<=-4-x<=y (the bottom half).